# Upload image into gravatar using python django

Tags: python, django, gravatar

Is there any way to upload gravatar image in https://secure.gravatar.com/ using python django ?
I am new to python and
I got this link as documentation https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/xmlrpc/. But I was not able to find how the process will work in python and what type of keys are needed for the implementation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the xmlrpc python client for this.

- Python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html
- Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html

Something on the lines of (python 3):

```
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://secure.gravatar.com/xmlrpc?user=[email_hash]')
try:
    with open("new_grav_img", "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
        proxy.grav.saveData(base64img, rating, password)
except xmlrpc.client.ProtocolError as err:
    print("A protocol error occurred")
    print("URL: %s" % err.url)
    print("HTTP/HTTPS headers: %s" % err.headers)
    print("Error code: %d" % err.errcode)
    print("Error message: %s" % err.errmsg)
```